Wordpress SKU Specific number for each category
I want to know is it possible to have specific number for each categories?
for example ABC_12xxxx for Clothing category, ABC_15xxxx for Shoe categories and so on.
which plugin can help me?
I used "Easy Auto SKU Generator for WooCommerce" but i can't generate specific number for each categories, only i can generate prefix before the SKU for all product and categories as the same.

Each product has to have its own unique SKU. So, yeah, the only way to have something in common for them is to have a common prefix
